# How does PHP scandir work?

Tags: php, file, directory, scandir

I need to scan directory `/home/user/www/site/public_html/application` (full path by root).
scandir does perform it with even just `'application'` part of full path as argument and that's all going to be ok, I got now list of files and directories as result.
I am interesting how scandir does work with that path `'application'`? Ain't the argument should be a `full path by root`?
I did not found any explanation to this behavior on official php.net, unfortunately.
Any idea, how it works? Thanks.

P.S.
My `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set to `/home/user/www/site/public_html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relative paths it bases them on the script's current working directory, which you can find with [`getcwd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Comment: It turned out everything is very simple :)  Thanks a lot!